# Line break in Twilio

Tags: ruby, sms, twilio

I'm trying to format my [Twilio SMS via ruby](https://www.twilio.com/docs/ruby/install) to have line breaks so I can send an SMS like so:

"Please enter your order as such: 
- 3 beers 
- 2 glasses of red wine"

I've seen suggestions like use \n for php or enter '%a0' but none of these has worked.

Comment: Might be good to show some code.  If you are using chomp or strip, stop it.

Comment: I figured it out. \n works, but it needs to be within the string obviously and not at the end of the line. I'm going to update the original post to show what I did.

Comment: Yeah, we would have been able to spot that right away.  You can also do `r.sms "Please enter your order as such:\n- 3 beers\n- 2 glasses of red wine"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work:

```
r.sms "Please enter your order as such:" \n  
"- 3 beers" \n  
"- 2 glasses of red wine"
```

This does work:

```
r.sms "Please enter your order as such:\n" \  
"- 3 beers\n" \  
"- 2 glasses of red wine"
```